# Can't modify row inside MySQL's 8 Document store: collection to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysql-8.0

I want to save array of strings or numbers to mysql collection row.

When I use

```
$collection->add('{"_id": 4,"name":  ["aaa", "bbb"]}')->execute();
```

It will save inside collection as

```
{"_id": 4, "name": ["aaa", "bbb"]}
```

but when I want to modify existing row with

```
$collection->modify("_id = 4")->set("name",'["aaa", "ccc"]')->execute();
```

It will save inside collection as

```
{"_id": 1, "name": "[\"aaa\", \"ccc\"]"}
```

How can I modify row and it will stay array and won't be converted to string.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"Can't modify row inside mysql nosql collection to array"* MySQL NoSQL?  You mean MySQL's 8 Document store right?

Comment: Yes I mean MySQL's 8 Document store

Comment: I don't know the first thing about noSQL, but did you try without quotes, like the insert?
$collection->modify("_id = 4")->set("name",["aaa", "ccc"])->execute();

Comment: What are you using as PHP library to use MySQL's 8 document store to mine knowledge there are no native PHP drivers (jet) except some PHP extensions, pecl or custom build frameworks..  Also maybe you should be providing more PHP code..

Comment: I'm using this extension https://pecl.php.net/package/mysql_xdevapi

Comment: As @ErwinMoller mentioned, when you add the entire document, it's parsing it correctly as JSON, but when you attempt to set a single field, it's not reading your array as JSON.  That feels like the root of your issue - I'd focus on figuring out how to pass a JSON array or object to the `modify` command first.

Comment: When I insert the array without quotes it still save it as string. It looks like modify function parse everything to string and if this is the case I'm $*&#.

Comment: Ok so it parse everything to string. According to documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql-xdevapi-collectionmodify.set.php .